# Replace a Freescale MPX5050gp pressure sensor with a washing machine pressure switch?

Tags: sensor

I have an application where I'm using a Freescale MPX5050GP pressure sensor, then I do signal processing using software to detect peaks of pressure.

There are no more imports of that pressure sensor to my country (politics!).

Could it be possible to get a cheap washing machine water level pressure switch to do the same? My sensor measures from 0 to 7 psi and I'm working on the lower side of those values.

I can find no specs for those pressure switches.

Edit: proper question should be: Is there any resource where I can get the specs/data sheets of washing machine pressure switches? Can they be connected directly to a microcontroller digital input pin ?

Edit: I know the sensor gives an analog pressure value. I use it to trigger a signal when there is a peak in the pressure leven (the container gets hit), effectively using as a pressure switch I can tune to a very precise level.

Comment: Despite the two edits, this is still vague because you are asking if some unknown switch can be connected to some unknown micro and will then perform a function it's not designed for. I'm sure it's possible, I'm sure most pressure switches are suitable for connecting to a GPIO pin with the appropriate circuit. What you are trying to build is a mechanical/pneumatic system that has the response of your maths (possibly an integrator?), something that people did before computers were widespread in things like aircraft bomb computers.

Comment: ...I would also add that you could research other pressure sensors, plenty of MPX-style sensors fitted to cars to measure inlet manifold pressure/vacuum or turbo boost, usually called MAP (Manifold Absolute Pressure) sensors.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure switches, by definition are not an analogue output - they activate at a threshold of pressure and deactivate at a pressure slightly lower determined by the hysterisis of the mechanics and electrical contact.

The MPX5050GP has a linear analogue output representing pressure and not a switched (digital) output that triggers at some threshold of pressure.

Comment: I know, but given that I'm post-processing the analog output of the sensor to detect pressure "peaks", would a pressure switch work? I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any washing machine pressure sensors that output an analog value, nor any where you'd find a convenient data sheet.

You should consider simply buying a different pressure sensor.  There are many, many options aside from Freescale. Find out if Honeywell, Panasonic, STMicro, or Omron are available in your area.

There are also industrial adjustable pressure switches that may meet your needs.  You can do an internet search for them, though they are fairly expensive.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of washing machine water level pressure sensors. The common one is a mechanical sensor which is not the one you need. Usually, the mechanical sensor size is bigger than the digital one. And the digital one needs 5V Vcc to work.
I didn't open the digital sensor but as I found in a lot of new SAMSUNG washing machines, that they are using 3 pins pressure sensor. I assume it should include a MPX sensor inside.
but you should be careful cause there are a wide variety of MPX range. and you should find an adequate one to fit. Or you should design your own frequency divider/multiplier to reach the needed scale.

### I found inside other SAMSUNG manual the following information:

*5 DC32-30006P 1 SENSOR PRESSURE DN-S14,TERMINAL-TYPE
(DC5V)
ASS’Y PRESSURE S/W ERROR
* Generated Frequency Signal of WATER LEVEL(W/L) S/W (KHz)

### Abnormal W/L Level Low Level  =30KHz High Level = 15.00 KHz*

It means that the washing machine pressure sensor /Data/ pin gives a variable frequency signal which detects the pressure.

The washing machine pressure sensor block contains 3 pins 
1=GND ( which is connected with the door thermal switch and the PCB Ground
2= Then the Signal (Data) Pin.
3= The 5V Vcc pin. it can be found in the PCB layout.

[image: pressure sensor_Samsung SWV-1200F]

---

and in wikipedia:

The bar is defined using the SI unit pascal, namely: 1 bar ≡ 100000 Pa. 1 bar is therefore equal to:

100 kPa (in SI units)
1×105 N/m2 (alternative representation in SI units)
1000000 Ba (barye) (in cgs units)
and approximately equal to

0.987 atm
14.5038 psi absolute
29.53 inHg
750.06 mmHg
750.06 Torr

### 1019.72 cmH2O

Dr. Soubhi Sabbagh
GSM +963944416832
email: drsoubhi(at)gmail.com